# How can I tell in Dockerfile which comand I want to execute when input "docker run" command?

Tags: node.js, docker

It's beginning of my dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install node
RUN apt-get install npm
RUN apt-get install mongo
RUN mkdir app
COPY . app/
WORKDIR app
```

When I input `docker run <image name>`, my container must run `node index.js`
What I must do for it?

Comment: Add `CMD node index.js` at the end of your docker file?

Answer (score 1):

Janez comment will work, however, if your container MUST start with 'node index.js' you will want to use ENTRYPOINT:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install node
RUN apt-get install npm
RUN apt-get install mongo
RUN mkdir app
COPY . app/
WORKDIR app
ENTRYPOINT ["node", "index.js"]
```

There is an extensive discussion on [ENTYRYPOINT vs CMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile) here in Stackoverflow already if you'd like to know more about the difference between the two, or how they can be combined e.g.

```
ENTRYPOINT ["node"]
CMD ["index.js"]
```

with that instead you could call the container with an alternate js file i.e.

```
docker run -it <image-name> test.js
```

and now the container would start and run `node test.js` instead